# Form action duplicate whole page

Tags: php, html, forms, duplication

I try to use a html form to call a php script. The link to the from is: http://scryptpower.de/login. Everytime I click "Senden" the php script should be called, but everytime I click the button, the script location shows me in the url, but the script didn´t run. It duplicate the whole page.

HTML:

```
<html><body><form action="scripts/login.php" method="post"><input type="submit"></input></form></body></html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php echo "Hello World"; ?>
```

Maybe this is because I use cloudflare ?

Regards

Nico

Comment: try: `action="/scripts/login.php"`

Comment: have you any mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: Ok thanks, that fixed only the duplication, but the php script isn´t called.

Comment: Yes I have some rewrite rules for e.x. login.html /login

Comment: Check you have PHP installed. Create a test.php and add the following:
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: Yes I have php installed :) The register script works fine with mysql etc. the only script which doesn´t work is the login script. I upload this file to scryptpower.de/test.php

Comment: Can you access the login.php directly to see what it returns. Then try using the same whole url in your action. This will confirm that the login.php is working but your (short) URL is not correct.

Comment: Looks like the login page http://scryptpower.de/scripts/login.php. The login file also have a other icon like the others in the folder http://scryptpower.de/scripts/

Comment: Just look like a file without login in the name work scryptpower.de/test1.php

Comment: Ok scryptpower.de/scripts/test.php work fine, but scryptpower.de/scripts/1login.php doesn´t work LoL Thank you for your help :)

Comment: scryptpower.de/login and scryptpower.de/scripts/login.php are the same file. Basically posting the form to itself. You must have some if/else blocks in your login.php that is preventing the echoing of "Hello World". Can we see the php code of login.php?

Comment: It´s the php code from above <?php echo "Hello World"; ?> Maybe this has something to do with the rewrite engine ?

Comment: Yes definitely! redirecting back to the form page.

Comment: Ok I will try to fix it: .htaccess looks like this        RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule login login.html
RewriteRule register register.html
RewriteRule home index.html
RewriteRule pricing pricing.html
RewriteRule support support.html
RewriteRule verify scripts/verify.php